# Прояснение организации MVC веб

Tags: веб-программирование, mvc

Использование MVC паттерна для классического веб-приложения подразумевает нахождение View на клиентской части? Или я как-то неправильно понимаю концепцию?

Comment: mvc может быть полностью на сервере, а может быть полностью на клиенте (а на сервере просто тупо API например) .... буквы в MVC никак не привязаны к конкретной стороне

Comment: А как тогда будет происходить связь между клиентом и сервером? В моем понимании, запрос клиента попадает в контроллер, откуда уезжает в model, а затем происходит возврат результата. Где в такой организации находится view?

Comment: Т.к. сервер вполне себе может возвращать HTML - View всё также может вполне себе существовать там..... клиентская часть только лишь отсылает запросы и вставляет ответы...... например....